# AngualrJS - Like "real time" http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest, real-time

I am using `AngularJS 1.3` and I have a backend that supports only HTTP requests. (without WebSockets).

What is the best option for most "real time" data updates?
Right now I am using `$interval` and sending http request every second but I am not so satisfied I am always thinking maybe there is a better option.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, there's not really an alternative, but you may be able to optimize the behavior based on the characteristics of your data and/or the user interface.

To minimize the resource consumption, for example, pause any requests when the relevant aspects of the interface aren't visible (e.g. in a different "page" or even if the user has switched to a different browser tab).

If the data is high volume but doesn't change frequently, you could set up your server to return a `304 Not Modified` until the data actually changes.

You could also send only diffs instead of the full data set if that results in a significant bandwidth savings.